# can not restart squid with cronjob using python

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, squid

I have written a simple python script    to check if squid works normally

/scripts/proxychecker

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
import sys, os, time
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:3128/'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
        html = response.read()
except:
    #os.system("/etc/init.d/squid3 stop");
    #os.system("/etc/init.d/squid3 start");
    os.system("/etc/init.d/squid3 restart");
    #os.system("service squid3 restart");
```

I shutdown squid,  and  manually executed this script "/scripts/proxychecker  ", 
it did bring up squid 
but if I add this script to cron job:
  */1 * * * * /scripts/proxychecker >/root/debug.txt

it did not work 
and from /root/debug.txt
it said
"Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start squid3"

I do not think this is   the reason why   squid not be brought up

because I have changed command as bellows  , and still did not work

```
    #os.system("/etc/init.d/squid3 stop");
    #os.system("/etc/init.d/squid3 start");
    os.system("/etc/init.d/squid3 restart");
    #os.system("service squid3 restart");
```

it is a strange problem

also 
cron is created by root
and this script also executed by root, permission should not be the reason

Comment: Did you already try `restart squid`?

Comment: sure, I did. please notice my #"comment out" part of the script

Comment: I cannot see `restart squid` just `service squid restart`

Comment: great thanks ,it works. "/usr/sbin/squid3 restart "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `restart squid` instead of `service squid restart`.